# Same pattern of a special character in 2 strings. Check outline level code of two strings

Tags: c#, string

I have two strings like A.B.C.D_E and in other string I have "*.*.*.*_*" as shown in `str`.
I want to check if both string are at the same outline level code and both have the same structure.

I tried the following.

```
string str= "*.*.*.*_*";
str= str.Replace("*", "");
```

So I will get only dots and dashes and I can count them.

```
string abc = "A.B.C.D_E";
var count = Regex.Matches(abc, ".").Count;
var countdash = Regex.Matches(abc, "_").Count;
count= count+countdash;
```

If count is equal to characters in string one than the string have same format.
Unfortunately this solution does not work for different formats.
Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: You should convert both strings into only dots and dashes (use a regex to convert all non dots and dashes) and then compare them.

Comment: So I need to remove all the characters except dots and dashes.

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9 -] this give all characters and I can remove them.

Comment: but if other special character are present they are not deleted. Is there a way to only keep dot and dash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is remove all characters except dot and dashes and compare them.

```
private string RemoveExtraText(string value)
    {
        var allowedChars = "._";
        return new string(value.Where(c => allowedChars.Contains(c)).ToArray());
    }
```

for your string "A.B.C.D_E". This function will return "...._". Compare it to the other string and you can find if both have same pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
string abc = "*.*.*.*_*";
string str = "...._*";
bool isMatch = Regex.Replace(abc, "[^._]", "") == Regex.Replace(str,"[^._]","");
```

[^._] will match any characters that aren't a dot or dash

Comment: He wants to match two strings, not one against a pattern.